# I can't call the CSS and JS files in my project Laravel page

Tags: laravel

I have some files in my laravel project inside `public/assets`, however these files are not actually called (only using CDN that works).

- `app.blade.php`

```
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheets">
    <script type="text/javascript" href="{{ asset('assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="{{ asset('assets/jquery/jquery-3.6.1.slim.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="{{ asset('assets/fontawesome/41b4cd8ba8.js') }}"></script>
```

How to correctly call these files?

Comment: Hi! Where did you include this code in the page? And if you take a look in your network-tab of your browser's developertools, do you see any errors?

Comment: .env change APP_URL=http://localhost to correct url

Comment: @Milkmannetje no appear nothing error in inspect element.

Comment: `asset` is searching on the folder `assets` already

Comment: Maybe you can check if the path to the files are correct by displaying it as a string in the body of your document <p>{{ asset('assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}</p> And did you check what's happening in the network-tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `href` for the `link` tag should work.

`script` tag though doesn't support `href` attribute...
you need to change it to `src`.
more for the `script` supported attributes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attributes)

then assuming then paths you added are correct, it will work

Comment: i think i made a mistake. Thanks for your help.